# How to dynamically call all the images and display using *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have many images inside an assets folder which I'm trying to display using `*ngFor`

*.ts

```
this.assetsImages = ['12.jpg', 'tt.jpg', 'an.jpg', 'pn.png'];
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let image of assetsImages" >
      <img src="../../assets/{{image}}" height="100px" width="100px" >
</div>
```

Above I'm statically writing path of the images to display. But if I have a huge number of images I'd need to hard-code all paths which is not feasible.

Is there any alternate way to display all images dynamically?

Comment: No you can't. You'll have to list all of your files. You could also make a "bruteforce" function, but it's not really performance-wise ...

Comment: what if i store all images in certain folder?

Comment: The issue isn't the folder, it's the JS capability to do that. NodeJS can because it is server-sided, but you can't list folders in Javascript browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with frontend. What you need to is using your back-end and return file in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

.ts

```
this.assetsImages = ['../../assets/12.jpg', '../../assets/tt.jpg', 'an.jpg', '../../assets/pn.png'];
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let image of assetsImages" >
      <img [src]="image" height="100px" width="100px" >
</div>
```